# Add a AutoComplete ComboBox to RadRichTextBox (Telerik)

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, telerik

I need add a ComboBox that has a feature, like autocomplete of Visual Studio intellisense at time to write a word. Currently i have a span and i need covert it to a combobox like the picture:
[image]

The rich text box is a control of Telerik (http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radrichtextbox-overview.html)

Comment: Did you get the solution for this? if yes please share your findings.